# MVC5 IIS7.5 Win7 routes return 404

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-7-x64, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been searching for a solution and have had no luck.  I have seen plenty of questions on here where it is suggested to install KB980368, however I have the extensionless handlers in IIS so it did not need to install.  I tried  `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` and no luck so then I tried `<modules">
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>` and still no luck.    I have my app pool running 4.0 integrated and am at a loss.  All of the controllers/views follow the default route mapping yet no matter what I do I get a 404 not found on every view other than my default Home.

This is running on Win7 IIS 7.5 all updates applied.  Deploying the same code to Server 2012 R2 IIS all the routes work and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Well after more head banging on the desk I found the issue is a virtual path in SSRS.  This virtual path conflicts with the name of a view folder and it appears SSRS is intercepting the call.  Disable SSRS service and now I get a 503.  I updated my views and controller and now all works.  What a shitty job of MS notifying you that SSRS is stealing the traffic before it even hits IIS.